# Neuralnet library in R gives different output every time

Tags: r, neural-network

I am trying to run a neural network in R using the neuralnet library and every time I run it, it gives me different results. Often it says 'the algorithm did not converge'. I have tried varying the amount of hidden layers, the threshold, the repetitions and nothing seems to work. My dataset is about 1100 rows, across 41 columns, and I am trying to use 40 of the columns to predict the 41st. Does anyone have any advice? Here is the code for the implementation I am currently using:-

```
n <- names(train1)
f <- as.formula(paste("RESULT ~", paste(n[!n %in% "RESULT"], collapse = " + "))) 
nn <- neuralnet(f, data=train1, hidden=4,linear.output=FALSE, threshold = 0.1, rep=3)
```

Whereby train1 is my data set. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably, you are using to learn The bias and weight "stocastich gradient", it take different input each time... Stocastico gradient take a part of input to learn The net and not The full input like " gradient method

Comment: I suggest you to read this chapter, it's great. http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html

Answer (score 2):

You get a different result because the weights are randomly generated each time. If you want the exact same results you need to set a seed (?set.seed) or provide a set of weights yourself (the 'startweights' argument).